# Is there a way to get the rotation info of surface geometry in AR Core

Tags: java, android, opencv, arcore

I developed an AR application based on AR Core in Android. Because I also used ArUco marker to help me tarcking the object location in real-world, so it's nessesary to alline the coordinate system of detected surface geometry in AR Core with the ArUco marker. I took a screenshot of the surface geometry, they usally show in white dots in a triangle shape and will change sometime when the application detects significant orientation change of the smartphone.

[image]

I was failed to alline those 2 coordinate system because I don't know how to get the rotation info of that surface geometry, is there a way to achive that? Or I should try something eles to alline the coordinate system?

I tried to get the orientation of the smartphone by reading the data of accelerometer and gyroscope. But as I described before, the surface geometry didn't change immediately when the orientation changes. As a temporary solution, I can only visually align the two coordinate systems by applying a rotation matrix.